# get the facebook fanpage uid

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to retrieve the `page_id` of a fanpage on which my application is installed?

Answer (score 1):

In the developer application select your app from the "My Applications" bar, and on the main page for your app you'll see the "Application ID". That's it.

The URL for your app's page is then http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php, with your application id as the "id" parameter.